# 'for' loop through the database is not showing results

Tags: php

Essentially, I built a small text chat type application for me and my friends and now the messages seem to be getting kind of long on the page so I thought it be better if I could just display the latest 10 or 20 messages or so.

That said, I tried a `for` loop like so:

```
$row = mysqli_num_rows($dbqDoIt4_mssgs);
for($i = 0; $i<5; $i++){
    if($row[$i]<5){
        echo '<div class="holdChat"><span class="orangeBigger">' . strtoupper($row['user']). '</span>' . ' ' . '<span class="txtSaid">said:</span> ' . '<span style="color:#171717;">' . $row['mssg'] . '</span>' . '</div><br/>';
    }
}
```

This last part of the code is kind of long, but essentially it holds the CSS classes, etc. for a gray box with the database text in it.

It now does display five rows (or however many I tell it to). I get no errors for the code or PHP, but the message itself from the database does not show, so all I get are empty gray boxes on the HTML where the text is supposed to be.

I'm assuming, because maybe I'm referencing the $row as $row[i], that it's not directly picking up the message(?)

(I am building a small application to teach myself PHP.)

Comment: Please read the manual for [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://au.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {        
        $i++;
        echo '<div class="holdChat"><span class="orangeBigger">' . strtoupper($row['user']). '</span>' . ' ' . '<span class="txtSaid">said:</span> ' . '<span style="color:#171717;">' . $row['mssg'] . '</span>' . '</div><br/>';
        if ($i == 5)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

From the PHP documentation for `mysqli_num_rows`:

> mysqli_result::num_rows -- mysqli_num_rows — **Gets the number of rows in a result**

Your `$row` variable is being assigned a numeric value, which doesn't mean much when you loop through it.

I haven't worked with MySQLi, but with MySQL, you do this:

```
while ($row = mysql_query($query_string)) {
  ...
}
```

And while `$row` is being set (every loop is a new row), your code runs. Just add a counter to make sure you don't print more than five times and your code should work fine.

Comment: hello Blender and thanks for your quick reply. although yes you are correct about numrows returning the number of rows as a number, when i did in the message display field row['tablename here']; it displays...so im now quite sure why when i did that it works but when i loop through it it doesnt.  What do you mean add a new counter? sorry, im still green to all this.

Comment: i got it thanks, i had originally the while loop in there but i guess i went about the loop for an amout method wrong. its all good now thanks